# How do i write this method?

Tags: java

I'm actually trying to create an alarm clock but i'm a bit confused on how to write this method, this is the directions and what i have so far.

```
/**
* Formats the time one of the following ways:
* "It is the top-of-the-hour" (if the minutes is 0)
* "It is half-past the hour" (if the minutes is 30)
* "It is 23 minutes past the hour" (if the minutes is more than 0 and less than 30; use the correct number
* of minutes here (23 is just an example)
* "It is 10 minutes before the hour" (if the minutes is more than 30 and less than 60; use the correct number
* of minutes here (10 is just an example)
*
* @precondition clock != null
* @postcondition none
*
* @param clock the clock to format
* @return a string as described above
*/
public String formatMinutesInConversationalTone(AlarmClock clock) {
    if (clock == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("clock cannot be null");
    }
    if (clock.getMinutes() == 0) {
        return "It is the top-of-the-hour";
    }
    if(clock.getMinutes() == 30) {
    return "it is half past the hour";
    }
    if(clock.getMinutes() > 0 && clock.getMinutes() < 30) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ivar thanks for the correction

Comment: You'll want to use the `String.format()` method to build the return string. Insert the clock minutes, and the word "past" or "before", based on whether minutes are `<' or `>` 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use different conditions for minutes that are before and after the hour, and use `String.format` to create those strings:

```
public String formatMinutesInConversationalTone(AlarmClock clock) {
    if (clock == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("clock cannot be null");
    }

    int minutes = clock.getMinutes();
    if (minutes == 0) {
        return "It is the top-of-the-hour";
    }

    if (minutes == 30) {
        return "It is half past the hour";
    }

    if (minutes < 30) {
        return String.format("It is %d minutes past the hour", minutes);
    }

    return String.format("It is %d minutes before the hour", (60 - minutes));
}
```

Comment: This was a really big help, Thank You!

Comment: @richyrich if this answer solved your problem, press the gray check mark under the vote counter to "accept" the answer. This helps other users to see what answer you used that worked and it gives Mureinik a reputation boost for providing a good answer.